# why does {form.$valid} not match $scope.form.$valid

Tags: angularjs

in my html, i have an input type submit tag with the following attribute

```
disabled="{form.$valid}"
```

in my controller I have

```
if ($scope.form.$valid) {
```

If i remove the disabled attribute, I am able to submit the form, if I add it in, I am not.

Any idea why {form.$valid} does not match $scope.form.$valid ?

cheers

Comment: is it normal that you got simple brackets `{ ... }` instead of double brackets `{{ ... }}` ?

Comment: good spot, fixed that as well. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this notation:

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$valid">
```

It's angular `ngDisabled` core directive for doing what you want.